# How to set a state in react that reflects if a function has completed running or not?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, state

I have a function which takes a long time to run, and need to implement a type of 'loading' message in React which displays when the function starts and goes away once it finishes.

My first idea was something along the lines of,

```
const myComponent = () => {

    const [isLoadingState, setIsLoadingState] = useState(false)

    // This function gets triggered whenever certain states get updated
    function verySlowFunction(): {
        setIsLoadingState(true);
        // various function calls
        // which take a long amount of time
        // here
        setIsLoadingState(false);
    }

    return (
        <h1>Our component here</h1>
        {isFetchingState ? <h5>Currently loading...</h5> : ''}
    )
}
```

The idea being, when the function starts, 'isLoadingState' becomes 'true', and thus the component being returned at the bottom will show as "Currently loading...", and when it gets to the last line of the function, it sets it back to 'false', so that h5 component goes away. (The logic has been tested and works as-expected there).

The problem I run into with this approach is that, for whatever reason, setIsloadingState doesn't appear to be setting the component to true or false after the initial load.

Does anyone have any ideas what I might be doing wrong, or suggestions on better ways I could be doing this (without having to change the implementation of "verySlowFunction()"?

Comment: What is the "very slow function" doing?  If it's all synchronous/blocking code then it's going to block the thread until it completes.  Or if it's invoking asynchronous operations then `setIsLoadingState(false)` should be called after those operations complete, not after they're invoked.

Comment: The code is synchronous. The short version is that it's grabbing a bunch of data (which I know can be done asynchronously, but due to other developers' choices, I have to work with what I have) and parsing it, the query and subsequent formatting taking ~30 seconds. Setting the flag before it gets invoked might work though, thank you.

Comment: If the overall process is synchronous then it sounds like what's happening is simply that the browser is blocked (and therefore unresponsive) for the time it takes to complete the process, so there's no way for React to re-render anything in the middle of the process.  To offload a synchronous process to another thread you might try looking into [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).  That might allow you to offload that overall process into something that JavaScript can treat as asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a promise to handle this situation.

```
function SamplePromise() {
 var promise = new 
   Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  //Do something 
 resolve('your result')
 });
 return promise;
```

Then you can call this function and use then to get your data and change the loading state. Such as

```
await SamplePromise().then((data)=> 
 setIsLoadingState(false))
```

.then() will be called when your promise finishes doing the work.

Answer (score 1):

React 18 introduce new hook.

useTransition is a React Hook that lets you update the state without blocking the UI.

You can do like below:

```
function App() {
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
  const verySlowFunction = () => {...};

  useEffect(() => {
    startTransition(() => {
      verySlowFunction();
    });
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Our component here</h1>
      {isPending ? <h5>Currently loading...</h5> : ""}
    </>
  );
```

}